# How do I output a variable in Zapier's python node to an email?

Tags: python, zapier

My task is to: Create a simple program (using Google Forms > Google Sheets > Zapier > Email) that I could use to ask 10 questions to someone, and based on results, would then generate a report to give them.

I have everything figured out except the python part of Zapier, in which I am using if statements to generate the report based on their answers to specific questions. I have made a mock-up with the questions "How are you feeling?" and "What is your favourite food?" to test if it works. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to output the variables into the email. What am I supposed to do? I've tried using `return{}` but that doesn't seem to work, giving me the wrong variables for some reason. Here's my code:

```
feeling=input_data
favFood=input_data
feelingReport=()
foodReport=() 

if feeling == "happy":
    feelingReport = ("its nice you're happy")
elif feeling == "sad":
    feelingReport = ("its bad you're sad")
elif feeling == "excited":
    feelingReport = ("its nice you're excited")
elif feeling == "scared":
    feelingReport = ("its bad you're scared")

if favFood == "pizza":
    foodReport = ("pizza is my fav too")
elif favFood == "sushi":
    foodReport = ("sushi is ok i guess")
elif favFood == "burgers":
    foodReport = ("i hate burgers")

output = [{'feelingReport': feelingReport, 'foodReport': foodReport}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **output** statement to use the values in the next step

```
output = [{'feelingReport': feelingReport, 'foodReport': foodReport}]
```

In the image below, you can see how the values can be used in the next Zap:

[image: screenshot of the Zap settings where previous data is being used in the final Zap]

Also, if the newest values aren't being pulled in, try clicking on the **Refresh Fields** button at the end of the Zap.

(---added the below answer after further investigation in the comments---)

Variables from the previous Zap should also be accessed through the **input_data** object. For example say that you used the variables **data1** and **data2**. You should then be accessing those variables in the code like this:

```
feeling=input_data["data1"]
favFood=input_data["data2"]
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the Zap settings for accessing variables]

Comment: Thanks. I tried your step, but Zapier doesn't seem to let me get an output no matter what type of Zap I use. Even if I do it correctly. the output field is always blank. I will edit my original post to show my updated code.

Comment: Is the variable not appearing like in my screenshot? Or is the variable appearing, but it's just giving you blank values in your Zap tests.

Comment: The variable is not appearing like in the screenshots, and it gives blank values in the python testing phase.

Comment: The way you are accessing **input_data** may be incorrect.
In the **Input Data** section of the Python Zap, map out some custom variables to your Zap inputs. Say that you used the variables **data1** and **data2**.
You should then be accessing those variables in the code like this: ```feeling=input_data["data1"]``` and ```favFood=input_data["data2"]``` . Here's a screenshot for reference: https://ibb.co/jZJwM1F

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much. This worked! I spent so long trying to figure out what was wrong as I only know the most basic Python and this was my first time with Zapier. Thank you again!

Comment: Yay, thanks for trying it out! Glad it worked ^^ I'll go ahead to update my answer to include that final issue.